# How to list files from n biggest directories?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I am interested in finding n biggest subdirectories (eg. 3) in my current directory **AND THEN** listing all the files from them. **I am not interested in finding biggest files.** I know there are a lot of solutions for finding biggest files and that's not what I want.

I have found my 3 biggest subdirectories with line:

```
$ du -hs */ | sort -rh | head -3
```

with result:

```
212K    04/
52K     02/
20K     03/
```

but somehow I am not able to list files from these directories (piping with **ls** did't work). Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the results of your piped commands with a while loop:

```
du -hs */ | sort -rh | head -3 | while read -r size dir 
do
   ls -l "$dir"
done
```

As a one liner:

```
du -hs */ | sort -rh | head -3 | while read -r size dir ; do ls -l "$dir"; done
```

Thanks to [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) for suggesting the use of `read` in a `while` loop over a `for` loop using `awk`, to handle filenames with spaces and special characters in a more robust manner.

Comment: Or `cut -f 2` instead of `awk '{print $2}'`.

Comment: ... or `du -hs */ | sort -rh | head -3 | while read -r size dir; do ls -l "$dir"; done` which won't break if the directory names happen to contain whitespace

Answer (score 4):

Command substitution, with help from `awk` to get first 3 directories:

```
ls -l $(du -hs */ | sort -rh | awk 'NR==4{exit} {print $2}')
```

Assuming no directory name contains any whitespace or any unusual character.

Robust approach: handling any possible file (directory) name, outputting directory name as NUL separated in `awk`and taking help from `xargs` to deal with each directory:

```
du -0hs */ | sort -zrh | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} NR==4{exit} {printf("%s\0", $2)}' | \
    xargs -0 ls -l
```

Each directory content at a time:

```
du -0hs */ | sort -zrh | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} NR==4{exit} {printf("%s\0", $2)}' | \
    xargs -0 -I{} ls -l {}
```

Comment: I think you'd need to start with `du -0` and `sort -z` if you want to handle _any_ possible file name, including newlines...

Comment: I do wonder if (when) a future version of Ubuntu (or some other somewhat-known distro) will start using the kernel patch that limits the possible characters in filenames.